# Best oauth2 grant type for mobile application

Tags: spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on an app that asks for mobile phone number from user and I am implementing **oauth2** in out application, Can someone suggest a suitable grant type for this scenario. I decided for **implitcit**, but I found that is most companies disapproves of this grant type.Can someone suggestion best option here.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. (Of course) on your environment setup.

If you are using a Native App on the mobile device then you SHOULD use the [Appauth](https://appauth.io/) SDKs as defined in [RFC 8252 - OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) which is also the [Best Current Practice](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1818) (BCP: 212).

If you are using a mobile - API - Backend then generally the Authorization Code is best.

Comment: Authorization Code grant_type needs username and password, but I am not using user name and passord, only phone number, first verifying that with phone OTP, then if it is verified than creating token for that user.

Comment: The authorization code grant does NOT need username and password. jwilleke's answer is correct.

Comment: "only phone number" implies you can at most identify the device and have no binding for the user of the phone. You can use Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) provides a modern solution for protecting SPAs; but you still need to identify the user.